# Why is $-cN/z^\alpha$ a good approximation for $\ln(1-F(z))^N$?

Tags: probability, approximation, random-walk, levy-processes

Bertin's [*Statistical Physics of Complex Systems*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-79949-6), 3rd ed. p. 65 defines a "complementary cumulative distribution $\tilde{F}(z)$" equal to $\int_z^\infty p(x)\,dx$, where the density $p(z)$ is proportional to $1/x^{1+\alpha}$ (p. 64).  (Later in the book, p. 237, Bertin notes what I can work out myself, that $p(x)=\frac{\alpha x_0^\alpha}{x^{1+\alpha}}$, where $x_0$ is a minimum value for $x$.)  I'm assuming that $\alpha$ is positive.

In case it's relevant background for my real question below, it's puzzling to me that Bertin then says that

> we can approximate $\tilde{F}(z)$ by its asymptotic behavior at large $z$:
> $$\tilde{F}(z) \approx \frac{c}{z^\alpha}$$

where $c$ is a "proportionality constant".  This isn't an approximation, though.  For $c=x_0^\alpha$, $\tilde{F}(z) = \frac{c}{z^\alpha}$.  I think the claim about this being an approximation for large $z$ concerns the next point that Bertin makes, i.e. the one that I don't understand:

**Bertin claims that the following approximation is reasonable when $N$ is large:**

$$\ln\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)^N \approx -\frac{cN}{z^\alpha}$$

[The left hand side is as it is in the book; I interpret it as $\ln\left(\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)^N\right)$, since this appears without the log function on the previous page.]

So Bertin is implying that $\ln(1-\tilde{F}(z))$ is a good enough approximation of $(-\tilde{F}(z))$ that they can be substituted for each other when $1-\tilde{F}(z)$ is raised to the power $N$.

If $\tilde{F}(z)$ was very close to $1$ and $N$ was not too large, then in the product $(1-\tilde{F}(z))^N$, the term $\tilde{F}(z)^N$ could dominate, be the major part of the result.  Then maybe $-cN/z^\alpha$ would make sense as an approximation?  But in the quotation above Bertin said that the approximation would hold for "large $z$", and  in which case $c/z^\alpha$ should be small.  This is so even though, on the preceding page, Bertin said that he would focus on cases in which $\alpha<1$. If $\alpha$ was small, that would mean that $z^\alpha$ would grow slowly, but $z^\alpha$ still would be large for sufficiently large $z$.  And in any event, $N$ is supposed to be large.  So it seems as if $(1-\tilde{F}(z))^N$ should be close to $1$.  **Why is $(-\frac{cN}{z^\alpha})$ a good approximation for the log of this value?** Or am I supposed to assume that $\alpha$ is small enough that $z^\alpha$ is close to $c=x_0^\alpha$?  But I'm not sure how that would help.

[If you suspect that Bertin's claim depends on physics-specific background intuitions and that as a result it would be better to ask in physics.SE, feel free to suggest that.]

Comment: Does $\ln\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)^N$ mean $\left(\ln\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)\right)^N$ or $\ln\left(\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)^N\right) ?$

Comment: Thanks @Henry.  That's what's in the book.  I take it to mean the second, because earlier there are uses of that expression without the logarithm.

Comment: So you can say $\ln\left(\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)^N\right) =N\ln\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)$. Presumably the argument is that $\ln(1-x) \approx -x$ at least for small $x$, and that in talking about "asymptotic behavior at large $z$" this would make $\tilde{F}(z)$ small

Comment: I think I see @Henry. You're suggesting the overall strategy of the approximation is that for any quantity that is slightly less than 1, its log can be taken to be approximately equal to *any* small negative value. And $1-\tilde{F}(z)$ is such a quantity near 1, for large $z$. The justification for the rhs is then simply that it's *some* small negative value, and Bertin uses $-c/z^\alpha$ as this small value not because of some special relationship to the quantity on the lhs (though it has that), but because $-c/z^\alpha$ will turn out to be useful in the rest of his argument. Is that it?

Comment: That would be my guess.  I would not say "any small value", but $\ln\left(\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)^N\right) =N\ln\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right) \approx - N \tilde{F}(z) \approx  -N \dfrac{c}{z^\alpha}$ with the last approximation being the assumption about the shape of the tail of the distribution

Comment: @Henry, OK: you're saying that we needn't assume that $c$ has the value that would make the last step an equality, since the shape of the tail might be all that matters.  That helps explain Bertin's comment I quoted, that $\frac{c}{z^\alpha}$ is an approximation for $\tilde{F}(z)$.  Indeed $c$ is not important in what follows.  Thank you.  (Feel free to put it all into an answer if you'd like. I'm not entirely sure whether it's the correct interpretation, since I understand the math but not all of the purpose of what's next in the book, but this is very helpful. Not your job to read the book!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Requested from comments:*

You can say

$$\ln\left(\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right)^N\right) =N\ln\left(1-\tilde{F}(z)\right) \approx - N \tilde{F}(z) \approx  -N \dfrac{c}{z^\alpha}$$

- the equality is a standard property of logarithms
- the first approximation is from $\ln(1-x) \approx -x$ for small $x$, and the complementary CDF $\tilde{F}(z)$ will be small in the tail
- the second approximation is the stated assumption about the shape of the tail of the distribution (essentially saying it is close to a power law for large $z$)

Comment: Thanks again Henry.  (fwiw, having gotten past the approximation I asked about--with your help!--I don't currently think that the purpose of using $c/z^\alpha$ was the merely to have a small value with a long tail.  That's absolutely a very reasonable guess.  Now that I have studied Bertin's further remarks, I think that the use to which Bertin puts his claim is based on more than a long tail--the value $z^{-\alpha}$ as such is important--though the shape of the tail is implicitly is part of this further use.)